# How to check the laptop ID for the LCD panel manufacturer?

Tags: linux, hardware, display

How can I know the brand/model of the display used in a laptop?

I have been roaming with `dmidecode` but I haven't found that information.

Comment: take off the cover and look for labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your GPU and monitor can talk via i2c, you'll see your monitor model in a X.org log.

The commands to achieve that manually:

`sudo ddcutil detect` or `ddccontrol  -p`

Lastly you could download and install a [trial version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise) of Windows 10 Enterprise and install [SoftMCCS](https://www.entechtaiwan.com/lib/softmccs.shtm).

Comment: They can also install EDID and get some info with `sudo get-edid | parse-edid`. That has model and manufacturer in it. The laptop manufacturer may have flashed their own info over it - but maybe not. I can't test right now because I'm using an HP and HP makes their own displays, so it spits out the correct HP data.